# captar datos de ASP a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp, vbscript

tengo una duda quiero capturar datos de fechas de incio y termino de una consulta ASP a jQuery , estos datos me los envia a un correo, pero me muestra los datos en blanco.

```
 <%

dim i, Q
dim fInicio, fTermino
dim lCentros

' obtener fechas anteriores
fInicio  = DateAdd("d", -7, now())
fTermino = DateAdd("d", 6, fInicio)



' Listar centros notificados
  Q = "SELECT werks,"&_
 "      stort "&_
 "FROM dbo.SAP_ControlMineria_Notificacion "&_
 "WHERE id_usuario <> 'job' "&_
 "  AND fNotificacion BETWEEN '"& fInicio &"' AND '"& fTermino &"' "&_
 "GROUP BY werks, stort "&_
 "ORDER BY werks, stort;"



 lCentros = getDBP(Q)

%>


 <!-- fila -->
 <div class="row-fluid">
  ENVIO DE CORREO SEMANAL, REP 3


 </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
// Se enviara correo de notif. a Mantenimiento
var fecini  = $("#<%=fInicio%>").val();
var fecfin  = $("#<%=fTermino%>").val();
var werks   = 'M027';         
var stort   = 'SALVADORC2';           
var func    = 'normal';
var fechaNotif = $("#<%=fTermino%>").val();
 $.ajax({
    async:false,    
    cache:false,   
    dataType:"html",
    type: 'POST',   
    url: "rep3_notificacion.asp",
    data: {
            fecini:fecini
          , fecfin:fecfin  
          , werks:werks       
          , stort:stort       
          , func:func           
    }, 
    success:  function(respuesta){  
        $("#mostrarRep").html(respuesta);

        // enviar correo reporte mantenmiento
        $.post("rep3_notificacion_email.asp", { werks:werks , stort:stort , tablas:respuesta, fechaNotif:fechaNotif }, function(data) {
        }).done(function() {
            // enviar mensaje de ejecucion correcta
            window.location.href = "rep7_detalle.asp";
        }).fail(function() {
            window.location.href = "rep8_detalle.asp";
        });

    },
    beforeSend:function(){},
    error:function(objXMLHttpRequest){}
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fInicio` y `fTermino` son dos variables locales de tu script ASP, en la línea que las estás utilizando tienes un error conceptual de jQuery

Estas líneas

```
var fecini  = $("#<%=fInicio%>").val();
var fecfin  = $("#<%=fTermino%>").val();
```

y en particular este código lo que está haciendo es buscar un elemento en el DOM (un div, un input, un botón, etc) que se llame igual al valor de tu variable:

```
$("#<%=fInicio%>").val();
```

por ejemplo si el valor de la varibale es `20181224` está buscando un elemento que tenga ese `id` por ejemplo `<input type="text" id="20181224">` pero si no existe no tiene un valor que asignarles a tus variables.

En este caso debes asignarlas de esta forma:

```
var fecini  = "<%=fInicio%>";
var fecfin  = "<%=fTermino%>";
```

lo que se vería para el cliente como:

```
var fecini  = "20181210";
var fecfin  = "20181217";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , claro era un error conceptual :)